# I made this code where it will display the product of all positive integer inputs inputted by the user, but the output is wrong

Tags: c++

So we were tasked to create a program that will ask user a positive integer until the user inputted a non-positive number or zero and then display the product of all positive inputs.  Using function prototypes. Everything is working fine, however, the displayed output is wrong. I'm guessing it's related to the formula I used but I can't figure it out. Can someone help me please?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int accept_number(){
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    return x;
}

bool ispositive(int x){
    if (x > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int product(int x, int y){
    return (x*y);
}

void display (int a){
    cout << "The product is " << a << ".";
}

int main(){
    int userNum, total = 1;

    do {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        userNum = accept_number();
        total += product(userNum, total);
    } while (ispositive(userNum));

    cout << endl;
    display(total);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"the displayed output is wrong"*  What output are you getting? `0` or some garbage output?

Comment: `total += product(userNum, total)` is not correct. `total *= userNum` is what must be done here.

Comment: You *add* the product of the total and the new number. what you want is : `total *= userNum`

Comment: Also, note that no prototype is used in this code example

Comment: On a side note, `if (x > 0) return true; else return false;` --> `return x > 0;`. (But why not just write `while (userNum > 0)`?)

Comment: "the output I'm getting every time is 0" -- My guess is you are testing your program by entering `0` to exit. So you multiply `total` by `0` before checking the loop end condition.

Comment: After writing the code and make it compiling, there is a third step which can be rarely skipped: test and debug the code. With single step debugging, you should've found all the issues mentioned in the comments and answers. (Even, after 25 years in business, I must admit that debugging is an essential step, and I can count the occasions on one hand where written code did what it was supposed to without debugging.)

Comment: I did, it's resolved now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you input 2 at the beginning of the program. Now you'd expect total to be 2 (2*1 = 2). But with what you're doing, this is not the case:

```
total += product(userNum, total);
```

..substituting values in this case:

```
1 += product(2, 1);
```

..which is 3. What you're doing is adding the product of `userNum` and `total` to `total`, which, according to the question, is not you want to do here. Try this:

```
total *= userNum; // can also be written as total = total * userNum
```

Also, your code's loop is wrong. Why? Because if you enter a negative number, it will get multiplied to `total`, then the loop will be exited, which will lead to incorrect results. So you should restructure your loop as such:

```
int userNum = 1, total = 1; // initialize userNum = 1

do {
    total *= userNum; // this was the last instruction previously
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    userNum = accept_number();

} while (ispositive(userNum));
```

Answer (score 3):

I thik there are two minor issues on your code:

1. You want the product of all positive numbers, have I understood correctly? Then why the line `total += product(userNum, total);`? This calculates the product between the last input number and the total, and then **adds** it to total. If you need only the product, you should overwrite total, not update it with the product, i.e. something like `total = product(userNum, total)`, or directly `total *= userNum;`
2. In a do-while loop, the statement is checked for at the `while` level. This means that the loop exits only after the negative number has been taken into account for the product. You could either add an `if` statement before updating `total` and then directly exit your cycle with a `break` or something like that, actually it is a matter of coding style.

Comment: I up-voted but I don't consider these as _minor issues_. Actually, the OP didn't implement what is required or, in other words, it's a syntactically and semantically valid C++ program but not for what was asked for, or even shorter: the program is wrong. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the statement:

```
total += product(userNum, total);
```

In the above statement, you're adding in `total` the result returned by the call to `product`. Moreover, there is no need to call the function `product`. You can just directly multiply `total` with `userNum` as shown below:

```
//---vv----------->also note the * instead of +
total*= userNum; //there is no need to call any function
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/OabsbiaFn)